# Is there a package that allows for drawing a sine function based on a sine equation? I've only found ones based on plotting coordinates

Tags: python, drawing, trigonometry

I'm trying to write a program that displays a pattern made up of sine/cosine functions and was hoping to find a way to graph those functions using just their equation (as opposed to finding several points in the equation and constructing a graph based on those points).

I tried using matplotlib but since I'm not displaying any data, the numbering of the axes isn't necessary and detracts from the look I'm going for (which would be just a bunch of cool lines across the window and no numbers).
I've looked into using turtle, but it seems like that would require finding and graphing individual points (which I'm hoping to avoid).
Basically, I'm looking for recommendations on a way to draw sinusoidal curves without graphing software or finding individual points.

Comment: Why not use `matplotlib` and hide the `Axes`' spines/ticks/etc.?

Answer (score 0):

try SymPy which allows direct plotting of mathematical expressions. See example here:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html

Answer (score 0):

> I've looked into using turtle, but it seems like that would require
>   finding and graphing individual points

True, but you have full control and instead of having to turn off features you can just show what you want:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from math import pi, sin as sine, cos as cosine

screen = Screen()
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, -1.25, 2 * pi, 1.25)

s = Turtle(visible=False)
s.color('red')

c = Turtle(visible=False)
c.color('blue')

c.penup()
c.sety(1.0)
c.pendown()

angle = 0

while angle < 2 * pi:
    s.goto(angle, sine(angle))
    c.goto(angle, cosine(angle))
    angle += 0.1

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]